# Is there a way to not inherit CSS stylesheets for a widget?

Tags: widget, css

I have a widget that customers buy to put on their site. We're running into a problem where our widget styling is being overridden by our customers' CSS. Is there anyway to disable CSS inheritance for the widget so that the only style sheet it uses is our own widget styling file? The only way we've managed to try to address this is by writing a rule for every attribute being overridden which obviously isn't very scaleable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only possible if you use an iframe that hosts nothing but your widget. Stylesheets are not shared among frames in a page.

I'm not sure how you embed widgets but you can use `!important` on all properties you declare in your stylesheet.

Comment: You beated me by a second. An iframe is what I was proposing as the best alternative in these cases.

Comment: Even using `!important` can still be overriden with a sufficiently strong style sheet.

Comment: @ign Correct. I have never seen any other production-scale options for widgets besides iframes.

Comment: @cdeszaq In the case of a non-iframe it's the only choice. Do you suggest running a JavaScript that disables all stylesheets in the page except the widget's one? ;-)

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov - I wasn't saying that there was any better non-iFrame solution than `!important`, only that is isn't "bulletproof".

Comment: @cdeszaq Sorry if my comment sounded offensive. I though you could suggest another option.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov - Nope, it's all good. I never take offense on-line, especially where there's a good-natured `;-)` involved. `:-)`